# iPhone: Developing an iBook App

Tags: iphone, ibooks

I want to develop an iPhone iBook app which should be integrate with [Apple's iBooks](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibooks/id364709193?mt=8) library. I can build an App with PDFs and link them as per requirements but not sure how to give the Apple's iBook library functionalities like Font, Theme, Search, Bookmark etc! Are there automatically available when you integrate iBook with Apple's iBooks library?

Comment: Use Apple's App "iBooks Author", it's available for free in the Mac App Store

Comment: @BjörnKaiser It seems "iBooks Author" is only available for iPad! Can I use it to publish App for iPhones?

Comment: Interesting, didn't expect it to be only available for iPad books. Bad research on my side. I found this http://www.copyblogger.com/publish-in-ibookstore/ on Goole, maybe it helps you. Also check out Apple's FAQ about publishing on the iBooks Store http://www.apple.com/itunes/content-providers/book-faq.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. iBooks only reads ePub and PDF ebooks. Their textbooks are merely modified ePub files. iBooks doesn't run third-party applications, it just reads ebooks. Are you looking to create an application that mimics iBooks' functionality?

Comment: @BradLarson No I don't want to mimic iBooks functionality. I want to create an iBook app. The hard copy of book is already available in market. We want to convert that into App which will be integrated with iBooks library! We have all pdf files. I can write simple documentController and few navigation controllers to create iPhone app but it wouln't be integrated with iBooks library. Would it? Still I am looking for what could be the right way to create our App. Thanks.

Comment: @AppleDeveloper - Again, iBooks doesn't run third-party applications. It just reads ePub documents and PDF files. If you want to have something that can be read in iBooks, you'll need to create an ePub document, not an application. If you want to provide a level of interactivity beyond what's currently supported in the ePub files that iBooks can read, you'll have to do that independently of iBooks by providing an application through the App Store. iBooks will have no knowledge of this application.

Comment: Thanks again Brad! I want no more additional functionality. What all I want is my book app integrated with iBooks library. I was trying to download iBooks Author on my Mac but I will need to upgrade my Mac OS before doing it. Just last question, all I have is PDFs, so would it be simple to create ePub document by uploading PDFs? Thanks. If you know any good documentation links for this it would be great help for me. Thanks for being there.

Comment: Can u give any source code for beginner for developing ibook.

Comment: @Vineesh there's no source code. Use "iBooks Author" App on your MAC to create App integrated with iBooks.

Comment: Is it need to install iBook Author Application? .  I was think create by using Xcode.

Comment: Not sure but it seems you don't need XCode! Directly use that App. I haven't created this app as it wasn't signed off.